# Unicode support Odoo qweb report (PDF) in docker

Tags: docker, unicode, fonts, debian, odoo

I run in docker odoo 10, unicode font is not support in docker but without docker in my machine, it's work perfectly. How to work in unicode odoo 10 in docker?

Thanks for advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the required fonts in your Odoo server. For example Bengali fonts for Debian can be installed with this command:

```
apt-get install fonts-beng
```

Similarly other fonts have own packages. You can find list of Debian font packages in page https://packages.debian.org/stable/fonts/.

You can test the font first by installing it manually in your Odoo container and restarting the container like this:

```
$ docker exec -ti -u 0 your-odoo-container-name bash
root@yourcontainer:/# apt-get update
root@yourcontainer:/# apt-get install fonts-beng
root@yourcontainer:/# exit
$ docker restart your-odoo-container-name
```

When you see the fonts work, you should make the font installation already to the docker image by modifying the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I use odoo 13 with Docker and also have this problem.
I solve it instantly with this Thai-ready docker image.

I just change the docker image name in my docker-compose.yaml then it work perfectly!

https://github.com/poonlap/odoo-th

If you use Odoo 12-13, this could help you.